# Best way to power series expand in multiple variables?

Tags: replacement, series-expansion

A power series expansion of a multivariate function can be performed with the `Series` command, which performs each expansion consecutively.  The results can be a bit clunky, however.

Often "mixed" terms will show up.  For instance, a function f(x,y) expanded to the first order about zero in x then y will often have terms `a*x*y` with `a` some constant.  Since we've aske for a first-order expansion, terms like `a*x*y` are undesirable.  It is easy-enough to fix this in the two-variable case with something like this.

```
ReplaceAll[#,{x*y :> 0}]&
```

But in n variables, an explosion in the number of possible combinations becomes prohibitive to use this "by-hand" type of fix.  Is there an elegant solution to this?  I could write a routine to generate all combinations and corresponding list of replacement rules, but this seems... excessive.

Is there a better way to perform the expansion that avoids this?  Or is there an elegant simplification method?

Comment: The usual way to do this is to replace vars by t*vars, e.g. `Thread[{x,y,z}->t*{x,y,z}]`, then expand in `t`, then maybe use `Normal[expansion] /. t->1`. Modify as needed if not expanding at the origin (either translate or, if at infinity, use reciprocals-- whatever it takes so that you can expand at `t=0`).

Comment: Daniel, thank you for the helpful comment.  I've seen this solution before, but had forgotten it.  It works well, but when replacing variables in a differential equation (I'm using this to simplify coupled nonlinear partial differential equations), care must be taken to replacement only non-derivative terms, otherwise the expansion occurs in the derivative terms as well (which is _not_ desirable).  I may end up using this solution, however, because it's probably the easiest.

Comment: @RicoPicone If you could include an example in which Daniel Lichtblau's method does not work, this would seem less a duplicate of the question Jens linked.

Comment: @MichaelE2, my application where this issue arises is pretty esoteric, so I doubt it would be of general interest. Because I'm often changing variables of a differential equation, I have substitution routines that substitutes functions for functions, which account for the changes in variable of derivatives with ease. If I use these routines to substitute `{x,y,z}` for `t*{x,y,z}`, even terms that are derivatives of `{x,y,z}` will be replaced and these `t` coefficients will be expanded over---which is undesirable. However, I realize that most people will simply use `ReplaceAll`. Which works.