# I want to cut off secondary approximate parts

Tags: approximation

When I input to Mathematica as follows,

```
G = {
  {-1, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 1, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 1, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 1}};
h = {
  {-h00/2, h01, h02, h03},
  {0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0}};
L = G + h;
Lt = Transpose[L];
G2raw = Lt . G. L;
G2 = Expand[ G2raw ]
```

The value of G2 will be as follows.

> { {-1 - h00 - h00^2/4, h01 + (h00 h01)/2, h02 + (h00 h02)/2, h03 +
>   (h00 h03)/2},   {h01 + (h00 h01)/2, 1 - h01^2, -h01 h02, -h01 h03},
>   {h02 + (h00 h02)/2, -h01 h02, 1 - h02^2, -h02 h03},   {h03 + (h00
>   h03)/2, -h01 h03, -h02 h03, 1 - h03^2} }

If [h00,h01,h02,h03] are very small values,
I cut off secondary approximate parts and leave first approximate parts,
and I'd like to obtain the following output.

> { {-1 - h00, h01, h02, h03},   {h01, 1, 0, 0},   {h02, 0, 1, 0},
>   {h03, 0, 0, 1} }

What kind of input should be added to Mathematica
to obtain the above expected output ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello ! Please, visit the help centre and read more about proper code formatting guidelines and format your post accordingly. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest I think is to expand as a power series in a new variable `t`, after first changing the expression so that each variable of interest is multiplied by `t`. Expand to first order to remove all terms quadratic and higher. Then use `Normal` and substitute `t->1`.

smallvars = {h00, h01, h02, h03};
Normal[Series[G2 /. Thread[smallvars -> t*smallvars], {t, 0, 1}]] /. 
 t -> 1

(* Out[21]= {{-1 - h00, h01, h02, h03}, {h01, 1, 0, 0}, {h02, 0, 1, 
  0}, {h03, 0, 0, 1}} *)

Related from MSE:

[Best way to power series expand in multiple variables?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30807/best-way-to-power-series-expand-in-multiple-variables)

[nested series expansion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46659/nested-series-expansion/46676#46676)

[Multivariable Taylor expansion does not work as expected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected)

[nested series expansion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46659/nested-series-expansion)

Answer (score 1):

This is your input:

```
 G = {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
h = {{-h00/2, h01, h02, h03}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    0}};
L = G + h;
Lt = Transpose[L];
G2raw = Lt.G.L;
G2 = Expand[G2raw]
```

yielding the following:

```
(*
{{-1 - h00 - h00^2/4, h01 + (h00 h01)/2, h02 + (h00 h02)/2, 
  h03 + (h00 h03)/2}, {h01 + (h00 h01)/2, 
  1 - h01^2, -h01 h02, -h01 h03}, {h02 + (h00 h02)/2, -h01 h02, 
  1 - h02^2, -h02 h03}, {h03 + (h00 h03)/2, -h01 h03, -h02 h03, 
  1 - h03^2}}
*)
```

you may use the rule:

```
   G2 /. {h00^_Integer -> 0, h01^_Integer -> 0, h02^_Integer -> 0, 
  h03^_Integer -> 0, h00*(h01 | h02 | h03) -> 0, h01*(h02 | h03) -> 0,
   h02*h03 -> 0}

(*  {{-1 - h00, h01, h02, h03}, {h01, 1, 0, 0}, {h02, 0, 1, 0}, {h03, 0, 
  0, 1}}  *)
```

Have fun!

**Later edit**: You may do the same another way around. Let us prepare the list

```
     M=3;
    lst = (Table[
    ToExpression["h0" <> ToString[n]]*
     ToExpression["h0" <> ToString[m]], {n, 0, M}, {m, 0, M}] // 
   Flatten)

(* {h00^2, h00 h01, h00 h02, h00 h03, h00 h01, h01^2, h01 h02, h01 h03, 
 h00 h02, h01 h02, h02^2, h02 h03, h00 h03, h01 h03, h02 h03, h03^2}   *)
```

If you have more terms, play with M. Now I would like to replace in this list each term h0N by the rule `h0N->0`. This may be done using the function:

```
f[x_] := x -> 0;
```

as follows:

```
    f /@ lst2

(* {h00^2 -> 0, h00 h01 -> 0, h00 h02 -> 0, h00 h03 -> 0, h00 h01 -> 0, 
 h01^2 -> 0, h01 h02 -> 0, h01 h03 -> 0, h00 h02 -> 0, h01 h02 -> 0, 
 h02^2 -> 0, h02 h03 -> 0, h00 h03 -> 0, h01 h03 -> 0, h02 h03 -> 0, 
 h03^2 -> 0}  *)
```

Now we have all rules we need (provided, of course, you will not tell that you have also higher orders). We can operate G2:

```
    G2 /. f /@ lst2

(*  {{-1 - h00, h01, h02, h03}, {h01, 1, 0, 0}, {h02, 0, 1, 0}, {h03, 0, 
  0, 1}}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: It is made of this.
However, the number of the items which make 0 increases.
I thinks that a lot of descriptions seem to be needed when the variables are many.

Comment: @Naota Inamoto Have a look at the later edit.

Comment: It served as a reference plainly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
G = {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}} ;

h = {{-h00/2, h01, h02, h03}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    0}};

L = G + h ;

Lt = Transpose[L];

G2raw = Lt.G.L ;

G2 = Expand[G2raw] /.
  Thread[
   Times @@@
     Tuples[
      Variables[Level[G2raw, -1]],
      2] -> 0]
```

> {{-1 - h00, h01, h02, h03}, {h01, 1, 0, 0}, {h02, 0, 1, 0}, {h03, 0,
>   0, 1}}

Answer (score 0):

```
h0 = {h00, h01, h02, h03};
r = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Outer[Times, h0, h0] -> 0 // Thread

(* {h00^2 -> 0, h00 h01 -> 0, h00 h02 -> 0, h00 h03 -> 0, 
h01^2 -> 0, h01 h02 -> 0, h01 h03 -> 0, h02^2 -> 0, h02 h03 -> 0, 
h03^2 -> 0} *)
```

then apply list of rules `r` to your resoulting matrix

Comment: I do not know the method, how do I apply the list of rules to the resolving matrix. Can you tell me the method?

Comment: like this: G2/.r , assuming G2 to be your final matrix

Comment: Thank you.
It went successfully.